# Detect Screen idle or activity in Android/PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am using JQuery 1.4.2 along with PhoneGap to create an app. Is there a function or plugin available to detect an idle screen or active screen? I want to hide/show some navigation buttons with a function. Any direction would be really appreciated.

An example I have found, which did not work:

```
$('body').bind('touchstart',function() {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
});

$('body').bind('touchend', function() {
     myTimer = setInterval(function() { 
                          /* return user to homepage */
                        },30000);
});
```

and tried this as well, with no results:

```
 $("#eventPage").on("scrollstart",function() {

         $("#preEventBtn").hide();
        $("#nextEventBtn").hide();
});
```

Solution:

```
 $(document).on("scrollstart",function() {

         $("#preEventBtn").show();
        $("#nextEventBtn").show();
});

     $(document).on("scrollstop",function() {

             $("#preEventBtn").fadeOut().delay(5000);
            $("#nextEventBtn").fadeOut().delay(5000);
    });

     $(document).on("tap",function() {

             $("#preEventBtn").show();
            $("#nextEventBtn").show();
    });
```

Comment: can you provide an example of something similar?

Comment: Detecting touch and scroll events would be enough, would it not?  That's fairly trivial.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Archer Good point, I adjusted my question to be more specific. I can't get the scrollstart to work (example in question now), and I could not find any working code for detecting an idle screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help with your scrolling issue...

```
var _scrollTimeout = 0;
var $fixedDiv = $("#fixed-div");

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    clearTimeout(_scrollTimeout);
    $fixedDiv.stop().fadeIn(500);
    _scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $fixedDiv.stop().fadeOut(1000);
    }, 500);
});
```

It's obviously an example and you'll need to modify it to suit your specific needs, but here's a working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/tK2mY/2/

Comment: I really like this method, much smoother than my version. Thank you!